# How to install adminlte on netbeans 11

Tags: netbeans-11, adminfaces

I have just upgraded from netbeans 8.2 to Apache Netbeans 11 in order to start my first webapp. I would like to use adminfaces and I am stuck.

I first used the admin-starter project and cloned it from github. In netbeans IDE I always got the errorpage 500. After that I tried from scratch: New Project, Java with Maven, Web Application
This got me a nice demoPage with my Tomcat9.0 server. Now I tried all different type of things - did not get it to work.

[How to Install Adminlte template on netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221774/how-to-install-adminlte-template-on-netbeans)

Basically this is what I was looking for, but this does not work on Netbeans 11 anymore.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all I gone back to the original github project. Needless to say the problem has to do with java 11 and some depreciated functions. 
So for people who want to use adminfaces with Netbeans 11 and Java 11 (OpenJDK) and Tomcat 9.0:

1. Download admin-starter-tomcat-master.zip from github
2. Import in Netbeans. Rename Directory to admin-starter-tomcat.
3. add dependency for javax.annotation V1.3.2 in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

4. add dependency for javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This worked for me after waisting one week of my time.